# ifHCOutOctets doesn't working with snmpget

Tags: cisco, snmp, bandwidth, linux

How do i get `counter64` to monitor hight bandwidth using `snmp`?

Counter32 works!

```
spatel@MBP:~$ snmpget -v1 -c public switch.cisco.com ifOutOctets.50
IF-MIB::ifOutOctets.50 = Counter32: 2038072800
```

counter64 not working :(

```
 spatel@MBP:~$ snmpget -v1 -c public switch.cisco.com ifHCOutOctets.50
 Error in packet
 Reason: (noSuchName) There is no such variable name in this MIB.
 Failed object: IF-MIB::ifHCOutOctets.50
```

My binary also 64 bit

```
spatel@MBP:~$ file /usr/bin/snmpget
/usr/bin/snmpget: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with SNMPv2 (-v2c).  Are you sure the switch even supports ifXTable?

[Search [[here]](http://tools.cisco.com/ITDIT/MIBS/AdvancedSearch?MibSel=4548)]

Comment: You got it right!!! after using `-v2c` it works!

Answer (score 0):

SNMPv1 doesn't support the 64-bit counters, you must use SNMPv2c or SNMPv3 for that.

http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/support/docs/ip/simple-network-management-protocol-snmp/26007-faq-snmpcounter.html

Comment: True. But that's never stopped Cisco from *defining* it in their V1 mibs.

Comment: Of course, but it stays unreadable with snmpv1...